Multiple docker services with their own databases for Django seem to be cross-connecting
EDIT: Somehow this seems to have resolved itself in that Django is now correctly resolving a host of "db_service1", which removes any ambiguity.
I have no idea why this did not work initially.

We have multiple services, and when run locally each fires up their own docker container for postgres. Fine.
There's also an "admin services" repo with a docker compose file for things like pgAdmin that will connect to any running services for ease of use. We have external port mappings assigned for each service so we can run different services at the same time locally.
The problem is that for the admin services repo to work we've added a "common" network to the services that it needs to reach. It's fine for pgAdmin there as it connects to "db_service1", "db_service2" etc, which is the container_name value.
However, django DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] setting does not seem to like having "db_service1" as a value, and instead requires the actual service ID from the compose file, which is "db" on all the services.
And since docker doesn't use external IP addresses, but the internal ones, and the internal ones are all 5432 (postgres default), when I start up eg. service2, then service1 starts erroring with
relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...

The only explanation I have for this is that it is now suddenly trying to connect to the service2 database, because they are both on the "common" network so that the admin services repo can get at them.
If I could set "db_service1" as the HOST for the db in settings.py, it would be fine, but django doesn't like that at all.
(I've not checked as yet, but I'm going to assume the same thing is probably happening with redis...)
Things I've tried:

Changing DATABASES config to connect via localhost and the external container port.
Changing DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] to be db_service1 rather than just db

I could try and get everybody to change the compose settings in each repo so the actual service names are "db_service1" etc. rather than "db", but that's a huge PITA co-ordination wise, and I kind of feel django should be able to connect via container name (after all, pgAdmin does just fine connecting to "db_service1" !!)

This question looks like more about configuration than development, and then it may be better suited for other sites, like https://devops.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps https://serverfault.com/

Do you have a [mcve]?  Seeing two of the Compose files and their wiring might help.  If all of your services and databases have published ports, it might be easier to run the admin tools directly on the host, to avoid connecting the services' networks together.

@tevemadar I'm not convinced this is a purely docker thing. The solution may lie in how I tell Django how to find the correct service!

@DavidMaze We've been told to remove the admin tools from each service and have a common repo :) You'd need 2 seperate django projects with compose config to reproduce it, but it should be quite simple to do so.
